# Fastest way to enumerate or look for all empty Excel cells and change their style or do some other processing

Tags: c#, .net, excel, ms-office, office-interop

Which would be potentially a best way to enumerate or iterate or simply look for empty cells or cells with specific data structure in Excel, and later once you find it do some processing on it.

I tired Range, Value, Value2, etc but it takes fairly long time when Excel Sheet is considerably larger. I believe there must be some other efficient way.
It would be nice, if you can show some example snippet.

Comment: Don't think there is any "efficient" way to do this in Excel sorry. You will need to look through the sheet. What is it you are trying to do ?

Comment: @TheKingDave: Yes, I guess so. I am trying to open an Excel sheet, read it all to search for empty cells or some cells with specific data structure and then either process that data or make it red for example if it is empty. It takes considerable time sometimes when there is larger data in Excel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is relativley simple: get the array in one batch from excel (search SO for a how to) - test the values of the erray for empty cells and then acess only the empty cells in excel.

It is somewhat cumbersome, but the fastes way because iterating each cell is vastly slower than simply getting all data in a batch.

Comment: Its quite a clever approach. In fact, helped me in some other way as well. Just create an object array and write it in any possible way to Excel, process it, which ultimately makes it super fast, since you do not have to access Excel and iterate over it.
Process it at your end and implement the changes in Excel. Will post some code snippet here.
Thanks @Christian Sauer

Answer (score 1):

To find blank cells, use the `.SpecialCells` method of a range object.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range.specialcells(v=office.11).aspx

The `.specialCells` method returns a range object of the matching criteria (i.e., `xlCellTypeVisible`, `xlCellTypeBlanks`, etc.). You can then iterate of this range to perform your formatting, etc.

**Update** I'm not a C# programmer, but I can show you how I would do this in VBA. Assuming interop exposes most/all of the same methods and functionality, you should hopefully be able to translate this for your purposes.

```
Sub ColorVisibles()
Dim rng As Range
Dim rngBlanks As Range
Dim blanksExist As Boolean

'define your range
Set rng = Range("A1:AA300")

'check to make sure there are blank cells in the range:
blanksExist = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(rng) > 0

If blanksExist Then
    Set rngBlanks = rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
    rngBlanks.Interior.Color = vbYellow

Else:
    MsgBox "No blank cells exist in the specified range.", vbInformation
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: I searched more about `.SpecialCells` and found this, which made me not to use `.SpecialCells`
**"If there are not any cells by specified criteria then function throw exception"**
Otherwise, it seems to be a better way.

Comment: Yes, if there are no cells found it will get a `1004` error, but this would be easy enough to trap & avoid with a `COUNTA` function.

Comment: great, sounds well. Got it, will give it a try. Thanks

Comment: Could you please (if possible) show me some example how to do this. I mean, find empty cell and then change interior color etc. It took me 4 minutes to process 380 X 40 excel sheet, which is not really much acceptable. Some how when I access cell using indices, it makes it too slow (especially on Excel 2013)

Comment: I don't know C# but I can show you how I'd do it in VBA, if that will help.

Comment: Ohh, thanks. Yeap, I will try some more and see if can find a solution. Will post it here.